# Redux does not recognize dispatch action in connect statement

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux

I am trying to implement logout into the side-bar of my application. The side-bar is also responsible to toggling some dialogs related to another state. the dialog state seems to have no issue. However, when I try to dispatch my logout action it throws this error

````
  Type '(dispatch: Dispatch<{ type: "[Auth] LOGIN_REQUEST"; payload: Credentials; } | { type: "[Auth] LOGIN_SUCCESS"; payload: Credentials; } | { type: "[Auth] LOGIN_FAILURE"; } | { type: "[Auth] LOGOUT"; }>) => { ...; }' is not assignable to type 'MapDispatchToPropsFactory<DispatchProps, OwnProps>'.
    Type '{ logout: () => { type: "[Auth] LOGOUT"; }; }' is not assignable to type 'MapDispatchToPropsFunction<DispatchProps, OwnProps>'.
      Type '{ logout: () => { type: "[Auth] LOGOUT"; }; }' provides no match for the signature '(dispatch: Dispatch<Action<any>>, ownProps: OwnProps): DispatchProps'.```

WHAT DOES IT MEAN PROVIDES NO MATCH FOR THE SIGNATURE! I've tried everything I can think of...
````

this is my code for passing the action to (connect):

```
interface DispatchProps {
  showBreachForm: (isOpen: boolean) => void
  showOPIForm: (isOpen: boolean) => void
  showPreapprovalForm: (isOpen: boolean) => void
  toggleDialog: (isOpen: boolean) => void
  logout: () => void
}


const MapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch<fromDialogActions.Actions>, ownProps: OwnProps) => ({
  showBForm: (isOpen: boolean) => dispatch(fromDialogActions.actions.showBForm(isOpen)),
  showOForm: (isOpen: boolean) => dispatch(fromDialogActions.actions.showOForm(isOpen)),
  showPForm: (isOpen: boolean) => dispatch(fromDialogActions.actions.showPForm(isOpen)),
  toggleDialog: (isOpen: boolean) => dispatch(fromDialogActions.actions.toggleDialog(isOpen)),
})

const MapLogoutToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch<fromActions.Actions>) => ({
  logout: () => dispatch(fromActions.actions.logout())
})

export default withRouter(
  connect<StateProps, DispatchProps, OwnProps>(
    MapStateToProps,
    MapLogoutToProps,
    MapDispatchToProps,
  )(SideBar as any)
)
//the error occurs in the above statement on MapLogoutToProps
```

PROGRESS: The Connect function works if I remove the withRouter wrapper. However, that needs to be there. Maybe clashing types is causing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

[mapDispatchToProps](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect#mapdispatchtoprops-object-dispatch-ownprops-object) expects a function which takes a second optional argument `ownProps`.

Try this code:

```
const MapLogoutToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch<fromActions.Actions>, ownProps?: OwnProps) => ({
  logout: () => dispatch(fromActions.actions.logout())
})
```

If it helps with `MapLogoutToProps` then you are likely to get similar error with `MapDispatchToProps` because the third argument to `connect` should be [mergeProps](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect#mergeprops-stateprops-dispatchprops-ownprops-object) with a different signature.

Comment: adding ownProps doesn't work. I had it there before but I removed it as it was unecessary

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution I wasn't aware of the COMPOSE function and typescript debugging is useless in helping with this situation

```
const MapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch, ownProps: OwnProps) => ({
  showBForm: (isOpen: boolean) => dispatch(fromDialogActions.actions.showBForm(isOpen)),
  showOForm: (isOpen: boolean) => dispatch(fromDialogActions.actions.showOForm(isOpen)),
  showPForm: (isOpen: boolean) => dispatch(fromDialogActions.actions.showPForm(isOpen)),
  toggleDialog: (isOpen: boolean) => dispatch(fromDialogActions.actions.toggleDialog(isOpen)),
  logout: () => dispatch(fromActions.actions.logout())
})


export default compose(
    withRouter
)(
  connect<StateProps, DispatchProps, OwnProps>(
    MapStateToProps,
    MapDispatchToProps,
  )(SideBar as any))
```